# How to design a piece of middleware that simplifies the login process

Tags: java, security, authentication, https, architecture

Currently I have devices (labeled CD in the graphic) where users login via a web interface to get some work assignment from a server (labeled S). It is a robust touch device where it is cumbersome to type in the credentials. Basically, the server creates some HTML and the user hits a big next button. The scenario is shown in **1**.

As one potential solution I have in mind that the users login via a desktop PC (labeled K). Some kind of middleware (labeled M) creates the session against the server (labeled S) and returns a simple 4 digit code. The user walks over to the workplace and types in the 4 digits in a web interface provided by the middleware. The middleware forwards every request from the user and every response from the server. The scenario is shown in **2**.

It would be easier to move the session from the middleware to the users device, but as all connections are HTTPS I would have to transfer the master secret etc. and I guess that's close to impossible and probably stupid. But I could establish a connection between server and middleware and middleware and user device (back to back). The middleware would be a simple Java application running on a tomcat.

The questions are: Is the approach suitable or are there better ways to achieve more comfort during the login process for the users?

[image: Current and proposed setup.]

Comment: I built a system like this 22 years ago. It took eight weeks to build, and the architect four or five weeks to specify before that. Too broad.

Comment: Picture link is dead